# Why does AWS S3 JDK Java gives me Check your key and signing method?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

```
AWSCredentials l_credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
        <Access Key>,
        <Secret Key>
    );
AmazonS3 amazonS3Cleint  = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
        .standard()
        .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1)
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(l_credentials))
        .build();
URI fileToBeDownloaded = new URI("https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/private/service/entity/19/04/1554190039-first%20last.csv");
AmazonS3URI s3URI = new AmazonS3URI(fileToBeDownloaded);
S3Object l_object =  amazonS3Cleint.getObject(s3URI.getBucket(), s3URI.getKey());
```

gives me

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: 621B7DD7DDCA0734; S3 Extended Request ID: HLjCevVe8qEEbcn0X4p5CvLGEF5traDzXviP1NzuA3vN10GpDfe60vw7eIUN13Z/JedEowAcYMc=), S3 Extended Request ID: HLjCevVe8qEEbcn0X4p5CvLGEF5traDzXviP1NzuA3vN10GpDfe60vw7eIUN13Z/JedEowAcYMc=
```

The credentials are correct. I am able to check everything for the bucket using aws s3 cli. Can someone check what I am doing wrong? I am not also able to list buckets using this client. I guess there is some problem in initiating the Amazon client.

Comment: `
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
`

Comment: I've faced this issue various times. This might be because the credentials are wrong.